# Por que mi onclick no funciona con una variable PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este codigo php

```
    $longitud = count($emotions);
    for ($i=1; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
    echo '
    <img src="images/emojis/emoji'.$i.'.png" 
    onclick="changeValue('.$emotions[$i].')" alt="Emoji" id="emojier" >
    ';
     }
```

y este javascript(esta en la misma pagina)

```
function changeValue(value){
 $("#texter").val($("#texter").val()+value);
}
```

Lo que hace esto es que añade el valor que le envio a un input, el valor es el del array[i] lo que no entiendo es por que no funciona si no da error, si cambio el valor que envio a "$i" funciona todo correctamente, entonces no entiendo. Por favor, ayudenme. Gracias.

Comment: Que es lo que contiene el array `$emotions`?

Comment: que tal si cambias tu cadena: "<img src='images/emojis/emoji$i.png' 
    onclick='changeValue('$emotions[$i]')' alt='Emoji' id='emojier' >"

Comment: Usar funciones *in line*  es una mala práctica, no se respeta el principio de separación de código. Si mañana tu función `changeValue()` necesita manejar otro parámetro y la tienes *in line*  dentro de 500 o 5,000 archivos, vas a tener que empezar a buscar todos esos archivos para agregar ese nuevo parámetro. Otro problema menor, que es lo que te pasa a ti aquí, es que se crea un código totalmente confuso con tantas comillas e historias que hacen el código complicado.  Es mejor escuchar los elementos desde Javascript y lanzar desde allí tu función, así el HTML queda totalmente independiente.

Comment: No ha funcionado nada y  el array $emotions contiene una larga lista de strings, es decir estan entre "comillas" todos y separados por coma.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que le estás pasando un valor que no está encerrado entre comillas y entonces no lo toma como string. Prueba con esto:

```
$longitud = count($emotions);
for ($i=1; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
echo '
<img src="images/emojis/emoji'.$i.'.png" 
onclick="changeValue(\''.$emotions[$i].'\')" alt="Emoji" id="emojier" >
';
 }
```

Comment: No  funciona, da igual.

Comment: @Laan Perdón, eso daría un error por usar comillas dobles, ahí lo modifiqué por comillas simples